# receive data as float in processing programming from serial port

Tags: java, arduino, processing, simulink

below is a code from arduino:

```
typedef union{
  float number;
  uint8_t bytes[4];
} FLOATUNION_t;

FLOATUNION_t myValue;

float getFloat(){ 
 int cont = 0; 
 FLOATUNION_t f; 
 while (cont < 4 ){ 
 f.bytes[cont] = Serial.read() ; 
 cont = cont +1; 
 } 
 return f.number; 
}
```

is there any alternative to this for processing programming(java)?

totally i need a code which recieve binary data from serial port and i want that data in float type in processing programming.

originally i am sending some data through serial send block in Simulink to processing programming,  i am using processing.serial library , but i could not get thise bits and convert them to float or int.

Answer (score 1):

You need to :

1. buffer each byte a time from Simulink into Processing: Serial's [`buffer()`](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_buffer_.html) / [`serialEvent()`](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/serialEvent_.html) / [`readBytes(bytesFromSimulink)`](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_readBytes_.html) could work nicely in tandem here
2. pack the bytes into a an int (shifting bytes as needed) and `OR`-ing them:
   `int intBits = bytesFromSimulink[3] << 24 | bytesFromSimulink[2] << 16 | bytesFromSimulink[1] << 8  | bytesFromSimulink[0];`
3. convert the int to a float via `Float.intBitsToFloat()`: `floatFromSimulink = Float.intBitsToFloat( intBits );`

Here's a basic sketch to illustrate the ideas above:

```
import processing.serial.*;

// how many bytes are expecting sent in one go
final int SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 4;
// pre-allocate serial read buffer
byte[] bytesFromSimulink = new byte[SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE];
// float from bytes
float floatFromSimulink;

// serial port reference
final String PORT_NAME = "COM2"; 
final int    BAUD_RATE = 115200;
Serial simulinkPort;

void setup(){
  size(300, 300);
  
  try{
    simulinkPort = new Serial(this, PORT_NAME, BAUD_RATE);
    // only fire serialEvent() when the right number of bytes has been buffered
    simulinkPort.buffer(SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE);
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("error opening serial port(" + PORT_NAME + "): double check the port name, wiring and make sure the port isn't already open in another application");
    e.printStackTrace();
    exit();
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  // format bytes to hex and float to 2 decimal places
  text(String.format("hex: %s\nfloat: %.2f", hex(byteFromSimulink), floatFromSimulink), 
       10, 15); 
}

void serialEvent(Serial port) {
  port.readBytes(bytesFromSimulink);
  // pack bytes into a 32bit int (shifting each byte accordingly): double check the byte order (e.g. LSB / MSB)
  int intBits = bytesFromSimulink[3] << 24 | 
                bytesFromSimulink[2] << 16 | 
                bytesFromSimulink[1] << 8  | 
                bytesFromSimulink[0];
  // convert int to to float
  floatFromSimulink = Float.intBitsToFloat( intBits );
}

// pretty-print byte array
String hex(byte[] data){
  String output = "";
  for(byte singleByte : data){
    output += hex(singleByte) + ' ';
  }
  return output;
}
```

Hopefully the above just works, but bare in mind it's untested code.
There are two things I could think could go wrong:

1. The bytes not arriving in the correct order. (let's say Simulink is continuously streaming serial data, but Processing starts later and only catches data from the 2nd, 3rd or 4th byte instead of the first: data will be shifted). You can try to remove `buffer()`/`serialEvent()` with a blocking loop and getting one byte at a time (e.g. `if(simulinkPort.available() >= 1) myNewByte = simulinkPort.read();`) and counting / packing bytes into the byte array manually. You could also try a call/response approach: e.g. Simulink doesn't send any data until it receives a single character from Processing (let's say 'A'), then starts streaming, so Processing is ready to buffer 4 bytes at a time from the get go.
2. I'm not sure in which order the bytes are sent from simulink: above I'm assuming right to left, but it's the other way around simply swap indices: `int intBits = byteFromSimulink[0] << 24 | byteFromSimulink[1] << 16 | byteFromSimulink[2] << 8  | byteFromSimulink[3];`

The other gotcha in Java/Processing is that bytes are from -127 to 127 so you would want mask bytes when inspecting: `println(myByte & 0xFF);`

Based on g00se's suggestion in the comments bellow here's an attempt at a [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getFloat()) option:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import processing.serial.*;

// how many bytes are expecting sent in one go
final int SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 4;
// pre-allocate serial read buffer
ByteBuffer bytesFromSimulink; 
// float from bytes
float floatFromSimulink;

// serial port reference
final String PORT_NAME = "COM2"; 
final int    BAUD_RATE = 115200;
Serial simulinkPort;

void setup(){
  size(300, 300);
  
  try{
    simulinkPort = new Serial(this, PORT_NAME, BAUD_RATE);
    // only fire serialEvent() when the right number of bytes has been buffered
    simulinkPort.buffer(SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE);
    bytesFromSimulink = ByteBuffer.allocate(SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE);
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("error opening serial port(" + PORT_NAME + "): double check the port name, wiring and make sure the port isn't already open in another application");
    e.printStackTrace();
    exit();
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  // format bytes to hex and float to 2 decimal places
  text(String.format("hex: %s\nfloat: %.2f", hex(bytesFromSimulink), floatFromSimulink), 
       10, 15); 
}

void serialEvent(Serial port) {
  // pass new data to the byte buffer
  bytesFromSimulink.put(port.readBytes(SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE));
  // set the index back to 0
  bytesFromSimulink.rewind();
  // read the first (rewinded) 4 bytes as a float
  floatFromSimulink = bytesFromSimulink.getFloat();
}

// pretty-print byte array
String hex(ByteBuffer data){
  String output = "";
  for(int i = 0 ; i < data.limit(); i++){
    output += hex(data.get(i)) + ' ';
  }
  return output;
}
```

Comment: You might find the [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asFloatBuffer()) methods a little more convenient. Byte order changing possible too

Comment: Ooooh! Great idea: java.nio package has plenty of faster utilities and `ByteBuffer` also has `getFloat()` which sound perfect for this.

Comment: I have tried your code and for example: the input in Simulink was 25 and output of your code in binary format is like : 11001000000000000000000000000 but the binary format of 25 is 00000000000000000000000000011001

Comment: above issue has been solved I have just changed the LittleEndian to BigEndian and the bit order is true now. but I want to use this value for forthcoming calculation, how I can change this hex value to integer or float?

Comment: That's great news: looks like the data is coming in properly, just need to swap the byte order. If you're using the `byte[]` option simply swap the indices add mentioned above. If you're using the `ByteBuffer` option try setting [`order()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order(java.nio.ByteOrder)) to the right endian type.

Comment: If the answer was helpful please vote to and if was the solution to your problem mark it as such with the green check mark. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time. thank you

Comment: but there is issue, when reading data , data are not stable , apart from real data there are more strange data between readings, is there anyway to apply header and terminator in my code to make my code more consistent? for example I defined header: A and terminator : '\n' in Simulink

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. You do have a few simple options like ['\n' terminator option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544784/matlab-simulink-to-processing-programming-serial-communication) or the [serial call response](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/SerialCallResponse) option mentioned above. Note that with the '\n' option if you want to send 10 ('\n') as part of the payload data you may accidentally truncate the 4 byte packet. Ideally you would want to develop your own protocol with a header/payload and checksum to ensure stable communication.

Comment: ...If you're manually reading one byte at a time using a counter you could check if '\n' was the 5th byte received, otherwise '\n' should be treated as the value 10 (`0x0A` / `00001010`) and the byte count should continue. If '\n' is found at an index greater than 5 then something is not right: reset the byte counter and keep trying to buffer bytes in the hope the next packet has the right structure)